# What are the available options for "Name" in WP search?

Tags: search, codex

I am trying to find the list of available values for `name` in the search to filter results.  So far I have found `name="s"` is the default `name="cat"` is for categories and `name="post_type"` is for post types.  I am relatively new to WP and I am finding it hard to know how to find details like this.

Can you please show me where in the codex these options came from?

Other resources are appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two `name`'s:

- The `name` query variable
- The `name` attribute in an input tag

### The Query Variable

`name` represents the post slug.

For example, I have a blog post on my site:

https://tomjn.com/2018/07/23/deployment-and-wordpress/

It has this post name:

`deployment-and-wordpress`

I can also visit this URL:

https://tomjn.com/?name=deployment-and-wordpress

I could also find it via `WP_Query` in code using this query:

```php
$query= = new WP_Query([
    'name' => 'deployment-and-wordpress'
]);
```

#### The `name="..."` attribute on an Input

As for the `name` parameter in a form input, those are query variables, the same ones passed to `WP_Query`. These are whitelisted internally, but you can refer to the WP_Query documentation for a full list and explanation:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Note that these docs assume you'll be writing PHP code, you may be better off using a `pre_get_posts` query to give yourself more options in some situations.

Using other values for the `name` input field won't have any effect on the main query, unless you write code to read it in and make changes yourself.

Keep in mind that this won't work if your themes template discards the main post query and creates a fresh brand new one of its own. That would be bad practice for numerous reasons, and I would suggest instead using the `pre_get_posts` filter to change what WP fetches from the database in PHP.

### A Note on Permalinks and Pretty URLs

When WordPress sees a pretty URL such as:

https://tomjn.com/2018/07/23/deployment-and-wordpress/

It uses the rewrite rule system to turn it into:

https://tomjn.com/index.php?name=deployment-and-wordpress

Then, once that's been done, it processes the result, passing the parameters that are query variables into a `WP_Query`, e.g.

```php
$wp_query = WP_Query([
    'name' => get_query_var( 'name' ),
]);
// etc
```

This is why adding parameters via form inputs or in the URL can change the posts WordPress retrieves, e.g. you can add `?s=test` to the end of a category archive to search in just that category, or add an `input` to change parameters, not just in search but on any WordPress post archive.

### A Final Note on The Codex

I would also note, that the codex is old, and was replaced by the dev hub at https://developer.wordpress.org/ many years ago. The Handbook and code reference on that site are far superior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and clarification

Comment: If this answers your question could you mark it as accepted? It's the tick under the voting buttons

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding of the question, even though it's accepted. I believe OP is referring to the fact that in the search form you can add `<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post">` so that only posts are searched (by adding `&post_type=post` to the search URL). They want to know what other parameters can be used in combination with `s` to filter results.

Comment: I see, I've ammended my answer to take that into account and explain both